# Refatorar o código usando JAX-RS

Tags: java, apache, http, post, jax-rs

Estou iniciando no mundo da programação e tenho que refatorar uma rotina usando outra biblioteca. A rotina usa a lib da apache para fazer requisições Http `org.apache.http.*`, tenho que refatorar usando Jax-RS.

Aqui está o exemplo da rotina que tenho que reescrever:

```
final SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            new BBRSocketFactory(config).getContext());
    try (final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory)
            .build()) {
        final HttpPost request = new HttpPost(config.getAmbiente().getUrl());
        request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pkcs7-signature");
        request.setEntity(new StringEntity(dadoEntradaAssinadoBase64));

        final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        System.out.println("Response status: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        final String stringResposta = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("Resposta string: " + stringResposta);
```

Duvidas:

- Qual a lib equivalente / Documentação.
- Qual os métodos correspondentes.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com o direcionamento de como fazer, ou até mesmo com algum exemplo ?

Comment: Você vai precisar se preocupar (ou seja, pesquisar) com 3 questões a partir do seu código de exemplo: 1) como fazer uma requisição POST usando o JAX-RS, também conhecido como Jersey; 2) como setar essa requisição para usar o protocolo SSL e 3) como setar os cabeçalhos (_headers_) da sua requisição.

Comment: Muito bom! Até o momento acredito que consigo fazer fazer o post e setar o cabeçalho. Estou pesquisando como setar o protocolo na requisição.